# What is the tag for web part description?

Tags: css, web-part, 2007

I would like to edit the font of the description in my RSS Viewer Web Part.  What is the css tag for the description?

I tried .description, which was provided from http://www.heathersolomon.com/content/sp07cssreference.htm but it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than answering your question directly, I want to strongly recommend that you use the Developer Tools in IE8 or Firebug to see what class that text has. Even if you are only occasionally going to do this sort of thing, you'll want to be familiar with one or both of these tools.

Comment: I have Chrome, thankfully, and it has the developer's tools, and it was .description, I was using it in the wrong context and the Chrome developer's tools showed me the tag.  The developer's tool will be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: My guess is that it was ms-description. Just wanted to be sure to get the right class here in case someone needs it.